# How to create a new table for a vector file?

Tags: grass-gis, vector

I will use `v.db.connect` but I want to use a new table, and not an existing table to connect it to. What is the GRASS script for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [v.db.addtable](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/v.db.addtable.html) -Creates and connects a new attribute table to a given layer of an existing vector map.